# Scope of global variable

Tags: php, global-variables

If I define a global variable outside of a function, why can't the function's code have access to it? The definition of global variable is that it can be accessed through out the code.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Please post your code here so we can help you.

Comment: or read the manual [http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: ...because it's the functions job to decide what variables should or shouldn't exist in it's scope. Also, you should really avoid the `global` keyword when ever possible (which is most of the time). It can cause a lot of headaches and strange side effects if you're not careful (and aren't the only developer).

Comment: Is the question "how do I use global variables in php" or "why was php designed like this"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass your variable into the function.
You can view this as a security measurement. If any function would see all global variables by default, it would be really easy to override something in the rest of your 50000 lines of code.

```
$myVar = 'asdf';

function doSomething($var){
    echo $var;
}

doSomething($myVar);
```

Or if you really don't want to pass it, you can do this:

```
$myVar = 'asdf';

function doSomething() {

    // tell the function that it should use a global var.
    global $myVar;

    echo $myVar;
}

doSomething();
```

There is one more way to call a variable directly in a function:

1. define your variable: `$myVar = 'asdf'`;
2. call your variable whereever you want, with this syntax: `$GLOBALS['myVar']`